# Secured excel sheet cannot expand/collapse grouped columns

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

We have an Excel spreadsheet with a secured/protected sheet. Only a small number of cells are open for editing. Now that it is protected, we cannot expand or collapse the columns in that sheet anymore.

Is there a way to do this, or can't this be done at all?

Comment: Can you add details about which version of Microsoft Excel you are using please.

Comment: @Nick Josevski : done, being busy with 2010 all this time makes me forget not everyone uses it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/view-hide-grouped-column-in-protected-worksheet/8405c089-e9c7-48f0-97c6-ec8169d6f2fb) on Microsoft Answers, you cannot expand or collapse grouped columns in a protected sheet.

It is possible to write a macro to show or hide the columns, rather than using grouping to do it, and then attaching the macro to a button on the sheet, as in the suggestion from that site:

```
Sub HideorUnhideColumns()
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
If Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then
   Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Else
   Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```